# objc How do I change the color of the first row of cells in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with two sections.
I want to change the `backgroundColor` attribute of the first row of cells in each section.

I have tried this:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)aCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 .... snip
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
 .....  snip 

}
```

but that only changes the color in Row 1, column 1.

Its strange but I cannot find a question like this.. Let me know and I'll delete this one.

UPDATE:

Number of sections..

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return self.dataArray.count;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionArray count];
}
```

The data array is junk data right now, but looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        [firstSection addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", i]];
        [secondSection addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item %d", i]];
    }

    self.dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstSection, secondSection, nil];
```

Comment: Did you try to use `indexPath.section`?

Comment: I need to clarify, I want the first row in each section to be red.

Comment: strange! it should work . can you try with cell.contentView.backgroundColor?

Comment: Are you sure you have 2 sections?

Comment: @Misha: same result.

Comment: @anhtu, yes, two sections. Right now, I'm getting the first row, first column in each section as red.

Comment: Try ashish 's implementation. It should work for you.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte I understand what problem you got. I just think, maybe you just got 1 section (e.g. return 1 in numOfSection ...). Can you check again?

Comment: can you post your code in `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte I said number of sections , you added for numberOfItemsInSections

Comment: oops..... but I don't see how the number of sections matters anyway. I'm seeing two sections in the sim. I don't see how my question relates to sections. Please advise.

Comment: the code is fine. It should work as it is . I was thinking maybe you aren't displaying 2 sections . Can you placea breakpoint on `[UIColor redColor]` / It it stops ?

Comment: @Misha, you got me thinking. It I have 4 sections, 1 and 3 with red color and 3 and 4 with white color, that perhaps could work. I'll try this and post back.

Answer (score 1):

Code the same snippet for the `else` part of the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` where you have set the section condition

Comment: There is no `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in a collection view. And please see my clarification above. Thanks

Comment: What i meant was `cellForItem`

Answer (score 1):

You have to check how many objects are in first row.

Take it in a variable like `numberOfObjectsInFirstRow`

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)aCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if(indexPath.row < numberOfObjectsInFirstRow)
     {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     }
     else
     {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add a different color in the else block :P

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)aCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if(indexPath.row == 0) {
         cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     } else {
         cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     }
}
```